# Symfony 3.2 form field with AJAX dropdown not populating

Tags: php, ajax, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

**AccountInvitation Form**

I want to load **Account**s for the specified **User** :

```
Invitor: [_Select User _______X]
Account: [_Select Account_____X]
```

Tried to implement [Dynamic Generation for Submitted Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) with no success. Changing the **User** dropdown and the **Account** dropdown remains empty.

```
Account --------{OneToMany}------- UserAccount --------{ManyToOne}-------- User
Account --------{OneToMany}------- AccountInvitation
```

**AccountInvitationType**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('email', LimitedEmailType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
        ))
        ->add('invitedBy', InvitorType::class);

    $formModifier = function(FormInterface $form, User $user = null) {

        $accounts = null === $user ? array() : $user->getAccounts();

        $form
            ->add('account', EntityType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'class' => Account::class,
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
                'choices' => $accounts,
            ));

    };

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
    function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

        $formModifier($event->getForm(), $event->getData()->getInvitedBy());

    });

    $builder->get('invitedBy')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
    function(FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {

        $event->stopPropagation();

        $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $event->getForm()->getData());

    }, 900);

}
```

AJAX call is ok, but the form in response, does not have the `$accounts` in it.

Using **Xdebug** & **PhpStorm**, the `$accounts` contains valid array, but it seems like `account` field does not get populated and added to the form.

**Question**

Why the `account` form field does not get populated upon changing the **User** dropdown?

## Update 1

AJAX call:

```
var $invitedBy = $('#accountinvitation_invitedBy');
$invitedBy.change(function() {

    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    var data = {};

    data[$invitedBy.attr('name')] = $invitedBy.val();
    $.ajax({
        url : $form.attr('action'),
        type: $form.attr('method'),
        data : data,
        success: function(html) {
            var replace = $(html).find('#accountinvitation_account');
            $('#accountinvitation_account').replaceWith(replace);
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Please ask more briefly

Comment: show me your ajax call